# Is there a fix for the “no WiFi adapter found” that doesn’t require internet?

Tags: wireless, adapter

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 on an acer laptop. I am trying to connect to the internet but it is saying no WiFi adapter found. I looked around the internet but all the fixes I have found require an Ethernet connection. I am currently quarantining in South Korea and do not have a Ethernet cable. My laptop connected to the internet before the trip. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of a fix or help me?

My adapter is a NetLink BCM57780 I believe.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that Netlink is your ethernet adapter. Run `lspci | grep -i wi` to find your wireless card.

Comment: You can always use your phone to get a temporary connection.

Comment: @mchid I cannot find anything listed as wireless adapter. I have ran the commands and only “Ethernet interface”comes up. 

My laptop was connecting just fine before and during the trip.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am not in my country right now so my phone service is not working right now. I did not have time to get a SIM card before my quarantine.

Comment: Okay, this should show it: `lspci | grep -i net` Also, if it worked before, I would first try to boot from a different kernel version from your grub menu to see if a kernel update caused the problem. From the grub menu, choose "advanced options" and then choose a different kernel version from the list.